# pointing Hostgator domain to Zerigo/DNsimple ALIAS

Tags: heroku

After reading about how a `my-app.herokuapp.com` cannot be referenced by an A Record by the simple fact that Heroku has a dynamic implementation of its servers, I chanced upon articles which extolled the uses of ALIAS functions in DNS services like Zerigo and DNsimple as a workaround for this issue.

This SO Post explains this problem has been solved, [Point top level domain to heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849324/point-top-level-domain-to-heroku-app)

However I do not follow how exactly to implement the solution.
Assuming I have a functional ALIAS setup in Zerigo which points to my `my-app.herokuapp.com` how do I then have my current webhost point to this ALIAS for the root domain?

Here is my Hostgator Control Panel which shows how the root domain (fls.net) is directed to a particular server via an A Record. I would like to subistute that A Record with my Zerigo ALIAS. How do I do that? Do I change my A Record to a CName? and then just put the ALIAS name in?

[image]

Note: 
This post: [How to redirect a root (naked) domain to www - heroku and zerigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529596/how-to-redirect-a-root-naked-domain-to-www-heroku-and-zerigo) seemed to have the same issue, except I don't understand why he calls the solution of using an ALIAS as "temporary". Why would it be a temporary solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your domain's name servers to point to Zerigo's name servers. You do this through your HostGator config. Zerigo has [an article](https://www.zerigo.com/docs/managed-dns/nameservers) on the name servers that your domain should use. [This article](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/domain-names-buy-sell-manage/changing-name-servers-with-launchpad) from HostGator explains how to change your domain's name servers. Basically, you want to log in to the HostGator portal and change the name server's to the one's listed in Zerigo's article.

---

Zerigo can handle the DNS for your domains, but only if DNS resolvers know to look at Zerigo instead of HostGator. Right now, when a DNS resolver (such as the one used by your computer's operating system) looks up the IP address to which `yourdomain.com` resolves, it first looks for the name servers that handle `yourdomain.com`, and then queries them. If the name servers point to HostGator, it doesn't matter what records you put in Zerigo, because HostGator will be queried for the domain's associated IP address. If you want Zerigo to handle the DNS resolution, you have to point the name servers to those managed by Zerigo instead.

Comment: But how does changing the name server, actually tell the domain where to find the ALIAS for the `my-app.herokuapp.com`? And will doing this change cause all of my current email to my-domain.com to break (Which currently uses Hostgator?)

Comment: sorry brother but I just don't understand how it works, and how much time I should wait for the DNS to propagate. Currently have a mail.my-domain.com record point to fls.net as a CNAME. when I change fls.net to point to heroku I will change that mail to the original Hostgator IP. That takes only 8 hours of time to propagate. My question is, if I mess with the nameservers, will that extend the time it takes for mail to change, to be the equivalent of 24-48 hours?

Comment: also is there anything preventing one from simply referring to `my-app.herokuapp.com` in the CNAME for `my-domain` . com in the hostgator control Panel?

Comment: Thank you for your thoroughness. You have to forgive me for my dullness. I understand that we want Zerigo to handle the DNS resolution, but the name servers are generic IPs used by everyone using Zerigo, Where is the specific information about what Zerigo / HerokuApp I am using passed from Hostgator to the Zerigo name servers. And I also don't know how this changing of my name servers to Zerigo will effect my mail, I suppose these are seperate questions I wound't mind chatting with you about it sometime if you would oblige.

Comment: Because currently my domain registrar has the hostgator name servers which resolve to hostgator which itself has name servers. So the flow of the DNS request will be from domain name to hostgator to zerigo which ultimately handle the DNS resolution. I don't understand the flow from hostgator to zerigo.

Comment: other than that you just put in some zerigo name servers on Hostgator *without changing any of the records on Hostgator*. Oh I guess the domain name, mycompany.com will be in the original request that domain register will pass to hostgator and then hostgator will pass that domain name to Zerigo, which will then look up in its own records for something that maps the domain name mycompany.com and finds the ALIAS that points to my app?

Comment: @Thalatta: If HostGator is not your domain registrar, then you will need to change the name servers through your registrar. Your registrar should have instructions for updating the name servers.